# possibility to take control in get and put jcache

Tags: caching, multi-tenant, infinispan, jcache

is there a possibility to take controle in get and put caches methods in jcache / infinispan to modify the key of the cache before getting cached?

I just want to take control to add the id of the tenant (case multi-tenancy application) in the key of the cache before putting it.

**PS: listeners are made to be executed after the cache getting created/updated... ( **not what i want** )**

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could describe how you setup Infinispan (embedded, as Hibernate's L2 cache, running in client-server mode, inside EAP, injecting caches via CDI...) - in the simplest case you could just wrap the Cache objects and adjust the key.

In the past it was possible to do what you describe using [custom interceptors](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#custom_interceptors_chapter) but that option is now deprecated.

Comment: hello, so im setuping  infinispan as embedded cache provider . is there a possibility if you don't mind to give me an example on how to wrap a cache object.